# getting the value of a selected key in a dictionary swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a set of dictionary that I defined and I am passing the value of the dictionary to an action sheet and I want to be able to access the key of the particular selected key. below is the code I have tried so far

```
func downloadPhotosData() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            "XXX1": [
                "code": "YYY1",
            ],
            "XXX2": [
                "code": "YYY2",
            ],
            "XXX3": [
                "code": "YYY3",
            ],
            "XXX4": [
                "code": "YYY4",
            ]
        ]
    }
```

I am able to pass the key into action sheet as such

```
 downloadPhotosData().keys.forEach {

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: $0, style: .default) { action in
                self.operatorLabel.text = action.title
........
```

which displays the key in the Alert Sheet but now I want to be able to print the value of `code` of the selected `key`. Any way to do that would be appriciated

I am able to get the `index` value of the selected action sheet as below but how do I get the `"code"` value of the selected index

```
if let index = sheet.actions.index(where: {$0 === action}){

                    print("INDEX \([index])")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `code` as below,

```
if let codeDict = self.downloadPhotosData()[action.title!] as? [String: String] {
     print(codeDict["code"]!)
}
```

Comment: how would it know that I selected `XXX1 or XXX2` to display get the corresponding value of `YYY1 or YYY2`

Comment: Put this code inside the `UIAlertAction` selection block where you are setting the label `self.operatorLabel.text` and see the console for the selected code.

Comment: I updated the question. Kindly check the base of the question

Comment: You don't need to loop the actions. Just use that `action.title` as above.

Answer (score 2):

In the loop you can do

```
 downloadPhotosData().keys.forEach( {
    if let code = downloadPhotosData()[$0] as? [String:String]
        print(code["code"])
    }
 })
```

Comment: how would it know that I selected `XXX1 or XXX2` to display get the corresponding value of `YYY1 or YYY2`

Comment: @King Maybe I misunderstood your question. What do you mean with selected here?

Comment: I updated the question. Kindly check the base of the question

Answer (score 2):

This could give you an idea

```
for obj in downloadPhotosData() {
    let mainKey = obj.key // the main Key which is XXXX
    let mainValue = obj.value as! [String: String] //which is dictionary
    let subKey  = mainValue.keys
    let subValues = mainValue.values
    // Out put for First obj
    print(mainKey) // XXX1
    print(mainValue) // ["code": "YYY1"]
    print(subKey) // ["code"]
    print(subValues) // [YYY1]
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Kindly check the base of the question

Answer (score 2):

If you need both the key and the value you can use the `forEach` method of a `dictionary` ([documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1689593-foreach))

This call:

```
downloadedPhotosData().forEach { (key, value) in
    print("Key is: \(key) - value is: \(value)")
}
```

Gives me this output:

> Key is: XXX1 - value is: ["code": "YYY1"]
>
> Key is: XXX4 - value is: ["code": "YYY4"]
>
> Key is: XXX2 - value is: ["code": "YYY2"]
>
> Key is: XXX3 - value is: ["code": "YYY3"]

### Update

So in your updated question you would like to use the inner value of the values in your dictionary.

You can loop through the `values` of the `dictionary` and then try to unwrap the value of the inner dictionary.

This should do the trick:

```
for innerDict in dict.values {
    if let value = innerDict["code"] {
        print("value is: \(value)")
    }
}
```

Gives me:

> value is: YYY1
>
> value is: YYY2
>
> value is: YYY4
>
> value is: YYY3

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I updated the question. Kindly check the base of the question

Comment: @King very well :) I've updated my answer as well then, but it seems you made it work already, glad you got it solved :)

Answer (score 2):

I've just done this in a playground, should be enough to solve your issue

```
var dict : [String : [String:String]] = [
"XXX1": [
    "code": "YYY1",
],
"XXX2": [
    "code": "YYY2",
],
"XXX3": [
    "code": "YYY3",
],
"XXX4": [
    "code": "YYY4",
]
]

dict.forEach { (x) in
    print(x.key)
    print(x.value["code"]!)
}
```

EDIT: Basically, something like this

```
func downloadPhotosData() -> [String : [String:String]] {
    return [
        "XXX1": [
            "code": "YYY1",
        ],
        "XXX2": [
            "code": "YYY2",
        ],
        "XXX3": [
            "code": "YYY3",
        ],
        "XXX4": [
            "code": "YYY4",
        ]
    ]
}
```

Then in your action sheet

```
downloadPhotosData().forEach { (x) in

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: x.key, style: .default) { action in
            self.operatorLabel.text = action.title
            print(x.value["code"]!)
            ........
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Kindly check the base of the question

Comment: So when a user taps a button you want the code to be printed?

Comment: thats what my solution prints out, you just need to put it in the action